# Struggling with JSON in text based RPG

Tags: javascript, json

I'm a game development student at university. For our first assignment we have to create a text based rpg (think fighting fantasy or the hobbit) in html and javascript.

The course itself teaches programming from the very beginning. I've been a front-end web developer for a year now and a game developer for almost 2 now, so I have a lot more experience with programming. Those of us that are more advanced are recommend to go above and beyond the assignment brief to get the best marks and show our motivation for the subject.

I've begun working on the code itself and it's been suggested to me that I should use JSON (or something similar) to store the data. This includes the text for dialogue and flavour text, stats and that sort of thing. So whilst I've been programming my constructors I've tried to work around the basis that I'll be somehow parsing in this data.

Whilst I know that JSON is javascript (basically), I've tried to look into using it and parsing it into my code but I'm really struggling to understand how it can be done. It's not a very well documented area, with the only real methods I've seen to parse in the JSON is with jQuert by passing the JSON object into another variable. Surely at this point I might as well just be storing the data within my JavaScript in the first place? Is there no way to search within the JSON document and read data directly without storing everything in my JavaScript again?

If anyone has any suggestions on how I should be doing this, or any alternatives and resources, then please point me in the right direction.

Thanks, Joeb.

Comment: Well, JSON is a data serialization format. To convert a data structure to a string in JSON format, you'd use `str = JSON.stringify(obj)`, and to parse a JSON string to data, you'd use `obj = JSON.parse(str)`.

Comment: The JSON string versions of objects allow you to more easily store them on disk/ file, or pass them between systems

Comment: It's a good practice to keep your data separate from your program.  Hard-coding data directly into your application can get messy and time-consuming to work around and can by itself introduce defects.  It's better to keep it separate in the event you want to save it off to a server or file.

Comment: I just had a look at stringify and parse, but it looks to me like they're converting javascript to json rather than the other way around?

Comment: Melpomene mentions this. JSON.stringify(yourObject) will turn your javascript object into a JSON string and JSON.parse(yourJSONString) will turn the string back into an object. The clue is that you use the string for storage on the server or for easily passing data between apps and then when you reload the strings inside your apps, parse them back into their objects, so you can reference all the data inside the object.